# mySQL Fetch the row which has the Max value for a column

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

How can I fetch the full row that contain the max(column).
Example:
I have a table like this

```
+----+---------------+------+---------------------+
| id | title         | c    | update              |
+----+---------------+------+---------------------+
|  1 | John S.       |   15 | 2017-09-15 09:04:13 |
|  1 | John S.       |   21 | 2017-09-15 09:04:29 |
|  1 | John S.       |   22 | 2017-09-16 01:55:26 |
| 43 | Cristover Co. |   15 | 2017-09-17 14:11:43 |
| 43 | PeterSberg R. |   16 | 2017-09-17 15:12:30 |
| 43 | Cristover Co. |   19 | 2017-09-17 21:45:10 |
+----+---------------+------+---------------------+
```

Now I want to select the row that contains the max(update). Expected result:

```
+----+---------------+------+---------------------+
| id | title         | c    | update              |
+----+---------------+------+---------------------+
| 43 | Cristover Co. |   19 | 2017-09-17 21:45:10 |
+----+---------------+------+---------------------+
```

Comment: ok. But first tell us what all you have tried?

Comment: update is a bad name for a column.

Comment: By "fetch" you mean "select" ? or have you selected those rows, but using `php` or something you want to select only the row with the max update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First,** you shouldn't name your column `update`, choose another name, let's say "date_of_update"

If you want to select only the row with the most recent update, you can simply use something like this :

```
SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY date_of_update DESC LIMIT 1.
```

This will give you only one row with the max date!

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
SELECT * FROM table_name 
    WHERE table_name.update = 
    (SELECT max(table_name.update) from table_name)
```